# Quasar - Missing .babelrc file

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, quasar-framework, quasar, babel-loader

I have an old project build with quasar, it was working good, until I changed my machine. when I try to run `quasar dev` I got this error:

⚠️  Missing .babelrc file...

While the same code works well on the old machine without `.babelrc` file needed.

My env:

```
node v12.22.12 
npm v6.14.16
quasar-cli 0.17.26
```

I tried to add this missing `.babelrc` file manually.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "check-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping"
  ]
}
```

but it shows me other more errors, because I don't know what exactly the content of it.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
  Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions'
```

I just tried to install these plugins but not work, keeps showing new errors.

```
error  in ./.quasar/app.styl
  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js):
```

I believe there is a solution without adding this file at all

I appreciate your help

Comment: Make sure you use the same quasar cli version on both machines, this is likely the way the machines are different. The project should preferably rely on local deps instead of global commands, i.e. have quasar-cli in devDependencies and use `npx quasar` instead of `quasar` if possible

Comment: Thanks, @EstusFlask, I will check the version on the old machine, somehow my old machine is not reachable right now.

Comment: `npx quasar` this is really awesome idea, because I'm also worried about if this will cause me an issue on my server after the deployment.

Comment: @EstusFlask again, your hint was very helpful and life-saving. I do really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed related to `quasar-cli` versions.

I finally resolved it, by using `npx quasar dev` instead of using the global quasar-cli.

Thanks to @EstusFlask for providing me with this Idea as he said

> Make sure you use the same quasar cli version on both machines, this is likely the way the machines are different. The project should preferably rely on local deps instead of global commands, i.e. have quasar-cli in devDependencies and use `npx quasar` instead of `quasar` if possible

I should use `npx quasar` from now and ever for running and building my apps rather than depending on the global quasar.